# apache camel : Ambiguous method invocations possible : JmsMessage

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using apache camel 2.12.1 and I have problem with my multiple onException statements. My route looks like:

```
<onException redeliveryPolicyRef="redeliveryPolicy1">
    <exception>com.somePackage.Exception1</exception>
    <handled>
       <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>
    <bean ref="errorHandler" />
</onException>


<onException redeliveryPolicyRef="redeliveryPolicy2">
    <exception>com.somePackage.Exception2</exception>
    <handled>
       <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>
    <bean ref="errorHandler" />
</onException>


<onException redeliveryPolicyRef="redeliveryPolicy3">
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
    <handled>
       <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>
    <bean ref="errorHandler" />
</onException>

<bean ref="bean1" />
<bean ref="bean2" />
<bean ref="bean3" />
```

In cases Exception1 or Exception2 occured while processing in beans my errorHandler is properly invoked(correct method binding). But in some other cases when let's say bean2 throws SomeOtherException I have problems with the last onException statement.

The error I get is:

Ambiguous method invocations possible: [Bean2.method1(Foo1), Bean2.method2(Foo2), Bead2.method3(Foo3) ]. Exchange[*JmsMessage*[JmsMessageID: ]]

Probably camel gets Exchange which is JmsMessage instead of my classes Foo1, Foo2. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Camel which method to call when its ambiguous, such as in the last onException

Change

```
<bean ref="errorHandler" />
```

To include the method attribute

```
<bean ref="errorHandler" method="nameOfMethodToCall" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was two ids with the same name.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="route">
        ...  
        <to uri="bean:processService" id="processService"/>           
        ...
    </route>
</camelContext>


<bean id="processService">

</bean>
```